# javascript observer pattern help in my code

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

Please help i m not getting what is mistake in my code. This is regarding observer pattern in js. Getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". I think this error is because "observers" key is not created on the object when i used it with new keyword.

Js Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2808w5x0/

```
function Subject(){
    this.observers = [];

  return {
    subscribeObserver:function(observer){
        observers.push(observer);
    },
    getObservers:function(){return this.observers;},
    unSubscribeObserver:function(observer){
        var index = this.observers.indexof(observer);
      if(index > -1){
        this.observers.splice(index,1);
      }
    },
    notifyObserver:function(observer){
        var index = this.observers.indexof(observer);
      if(index > -1){
        this.observer[index].notify(index);
      }
    },
    notifyAllObserver:function(){
        this.observers.foreach(function(val,idx){
        val.notify(idx);
      });
    }
  };
}

function Observer(){
    return{
    notify:function(idx){
        console.log("Observer " + idx + " notified.");
    }
  }
}

var subject = new Subject();
console.log("subject ",subject.getObservers());
var ob1 = new Observer();
var ob2 = new Observer();
var ob3 = new Observer();
var ob4 = new Observer();

subject.subscribeObserver(ob1);
subject.subscribeObserver(ob2);
subject.subscribeObserver(ob3);
subject.subscribeObserver(ob4);

subject.notifyAllObserver();
```

Comment: Please also mention what is wrong. You will have to specify the problem statement you need help with.

Comment: My apologies. Edited the post.

Comment: Should `observers.push(observer);` not be `this.observers.push(observer);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, when creating a new object `new Subject()` there is an implicit `return` that provides your new object. You don't need to return your object like you did.

---

Now, for the methods, you need to attach them to the **prototype of the object**. That way, when the object is created, *it will have those methods attached to it*. Ex :

```js
function MySuperObject( value ) {
    this.property = value;
};

MySuperObject.prototype.attachedMethod = function() {
    console.log("Property is equal to : " + this.property) + ".";
};

// The object is implicitly returned and stored in <myobj>.
var myobj = new MySuperObject(0);

// Result : Property is equal to : 0.
myobj.attachedMethod();
```

---

And so, your code must be written as :

```js
function Subject(){
  this.observers = [];
}

Subject.prototype.subscribeObserver = function( observer ) {
  this.observers.push(observer);
};

Subject.prototype.getObservers = function() {
  return "There are " + this.observers.length + " observers.";
};

function Observer(){
  // ...
}

var subject = new Subject();
console.log("subject ",subject.getObservers());

var ob1 = new Observer();
var ob2 = new Observer();
var ob3 = new Observer();
var ob4 = new Observer();
subject.subscribeObserver(ob1);
subject.subscribeObserver(ob2);
subject.subscribeObserver(ob3);
subject.subscribeObserver(ob4);

// Or you could simply do :
// for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
//     subject.subscribeObserver(new Observer());
// }

console.log("subject ",subject.getObservers());
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I have updated the code in jsfiddle, now its running good.